# How to use Math.cos() & Math.sin() properly?

Tags: actionscript-3, math, numbers, trigonometry

I've wrote some trace code to describe my problem.

```
GLOBALS.customTrace = "COS 0: " + String(Math.cos(0 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //OK\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "SIN 0: " + String(Math.sin(0 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //OK\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "COS 90: " + String(Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //WHY ?\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "SIN 90: " + String(Math.sin(90 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //OK\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "COS 180: " + String(Math.cos(180 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //OK\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "SIN 180: " + String(Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //WHY ?\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "COS 270: " + String(Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //WHY ?\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "SIN 270: " + String(Math.sin(270 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //OK\n";
```

The code above...

...returning this output.

[image: OUTPUT]

I don't know how to handle with this? I don't need real values **for whole angles**, but **i need real values of cos90, sin180, cos270 absolutely**!

Also, there is another issue, but i feel it is a result of the real problem above.
I'm using -180 and +180 both in this code, but both of them returning negative values.

```
GLOBALS.customTrace = "COS 270 with Math.PI / -180\n" + String(Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / -180)) + "   //IF THIS NEGATIVE...\n\n";
GLOBALS.customTrace += "COS 270: with Math.PI / +180\n" + String(Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / 180)) + "   //...WHY THIS NEGATIVE TOO ?\n";
```

The code above...

...returning this output

[image: OUTPUT2]

Comment: Do you understand what sin and cos actually are in mathematics?

Comment: That's just floating point arithmetic. If it bugs you, print the results only up to 6 significant digits; you will see what you expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: And the obligatory [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: So, problem not about trigonometry, the problem about precise numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `Math.PI != π`.

You can try `toFixed(15)` to get a precise value.

```
trace(String(Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)));
trace(String(Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)));
trace(String(Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)));
trace(String(Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)) == 0);
trace(String(Math.sin(180 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)) == 0);
trace(String(Math.cos(270 * Math.PI / -180).toFixed(15)) == 0);
```

OutPut.

```
0.000000000000000
-0.000000000000000
-0.000000000000000
true
true
true
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, @Ali said that. I've made that.